# GET API is not working above IOS 13.3 (Time Out) Alamofire 5.0

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, ios13.3

GET API is not working on above IOS 13.3 (Time Out) and I am using  Alamofire 5.0

Here is my API calling code.

```
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://geturl")!)
let urlString = urlRequest.url?.absoluteString

    AF.request(urlString!,method: .get, parameters: nil, headers:nil).responseJSON { response in

          debugPrint(response)
          switch response.result {
              case .success(let json):
                    print(json as Any
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    }
              case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
          }
     }
```

Comment: have you cross-checked with Postman? Is it working properly there?

Comment: Yes  its working in Postman & simulator too but only on device i am getting  timeout

Comment: maybe on your computer some proxy settings? try to call API with vpn

Comment: What’s the URLRequest for?. Practically it’s unused. You are creating an URL from a string, then the request from the URL, then getting back the URL and converting back to string. That’s pretty weird. And are you sure that the parameter is not supposed to be an URL?

Comment: @vadian Worked .. Some Proxy in Network so i connected to VPN its working fine, Thanks